# Remove Index in lwuit list

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have created List using LWUIT.
but is shows me item with index.
like

1. item-1
2. item-2
3. item-3

I want to remove left side index 1,2,3 how can I do that?

Code:

```
 class mainForm extends Form implements ActionListener{

        List list;

        String newkey = "";
        final String COMPANY[] = {"AIRCEL", "AIRTEL", "BPL", "BSNL", "IDEA", "RELIANCE", "TATA DOCOMO", "TATA INDICOM", "UNINOR", "VIRGIN", "VIDEOCON", "VODAFONE", "AIRCEL1", "AIRTEL2", "BPL1", "BSNL1", "IDEA1", "RELIANCE1", "TATA DOCOMO1", "TATA INDICOM1", "UNINOR1", "VIRGIN1", "VIDEOCON1"};
        final int CO_LENGTH = COMPANY.length;

        mainForm() {

            super("Main Form");
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            list = new List(COMPANY);
           list.addActionListener(this);


            list.setPreferredW(getWidth());

            addComponent(list);



        }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you post relevant code here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
list.setListCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer(false));
```

The [javadocs](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/list/DefaultListCellRenderer.html#DefaultListCellRenderer%28boolean%29) explains the reason for false "showLineNumbers"

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
private static class RemoveIndexRenderer extends Label implements ListCellRenderer {

    public RemoveIndexRenderer() {
        super("");
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {
        setText(value.toString());
        setFocus(isSelected);
        getStyle().setBgTransparency(100);
        return this;
    }

    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
        setText("");
        setFocus(true);
        getStyle().setBgTransparency(100);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And -

```
    List list = new List(listModel);
    RemoveIndexRenderer listCellRenderer = new RemoveIndexRenderer();
    list.setListCellRenderer(listCellRenderer);
```